# flags in chat yesterday

Tags: discussion, flagging, chat

There was some sort of excitement yesterday or last night which I found mysterious. It turns out that in Chat, and there is just the one main chat which has been going forever, one may either star a comment as good or flag it as bad in some way. Asking about it within chat seemed to get a lot of "Leave this alone," so I thought I would ask here where I might get a correct description of the issues, albeit perhaps without all detail.

EEDIITT: this was somewhere fairly late as far as the questionable events: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7824060#7824060

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yesterday, there were a number of chat comments flagged that were not really worthy of a flag, yet were flagged nonetheless. All moderators (whether in the same room or not) are notified of flags in any chat, as well as all users with 10K+ reputation get notified of chat flags. It is not surprising that some moderators and high rep users find excessive, unwarranted flagging somewhat annoying. Yesterday, some moderators and high rep users from other rooms dropped by to express annoyance.

Flagging in chat should be reserved for abuse, spam, etc. Flagging should not be used to punish another user or to express of a difference of opinion. Flags are not the opposite of stars.  Stars can be used more freely.